# Force change detection in pipe (pure or impure) bound to ngModel

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I'm binding an ngModel value to the angular percent pipe, updating on ngModelChange with updateOn set to blur. It works well except when entering the same value again. When entering the same value again, the pipe does not detect the change and the value shows as a decimal instead of a percent. I have tried recreating the percent pipe as an impure pipe but this did not work. How can I force the pipe to detect the change even if the value is identical to previous value?

Tried having pipe return `WrappedValue.wrap(this._latestValue)`;

Tried running `this._ref.detectChanges()` in change function

```html
<input placeholder="Percentage" type="text" 
       [ngModel]="account.percentage | percent: '1.0-2'"
       (ngModelChange)="updateAssignments($event)" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}" class="ta-r" />
```

```js
updateAssignments($event) {
    const cleanEvent = Number($event.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
    account.percentage = (cleanEvent / 100);
}
```

Expecting value to be displayed formatted as a percent. Shows decimal value after reentering.

[My Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-ru3ks1)

Comment: I don't understand why wouldn't it work... what does it matter if the pipe is pure? Same input same output right? Did the pipe just stopped working?

Comment: hey mah koreh gever? if its pure it only runs the pipe on input change, if its impure it runs every change detection cycle.

Comment: I've been hitting this issue for a few days now. Something is very fishy. My case is exactly like this, except I use (blur) and have a conditional pipe:

<input matInput name="hedgeAmount"
            placeholder="Hedge amount"
            [ngModel]="position.hedgeType === 0 ? (position.hedgeAmount / 100 | percent : '1.0-2') : (position.hedgeAmount | currency : position.CurrencyIsoCode : 'symbol-narrow')"
            (blur)="onBlurHedgeAmount($event)"/>

Did you figure out how to make this work?

Comment: @verynear set the accepted answer to ysf's when you have a moment and if the solution works for you.

Answer (score 3):

while trying to find a proper solution, i managed to force pure `currency` pipe to re-execute with same value ([here is the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-scju31)). but that didn't solve the problem because even if the pipe re-executes, it eventually returns same result. since that result is binded to `ngModel` as `@Input` like `[ngModel]="account.percentage | percent: '1.0-2'"` `ngOnChanges` hook in [ngModel implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e9faf8c78beba95a874819a4a44e91a505a42255/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L221) doesn't update input elements view value.

this is (taken from [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e9faf8c78beba95a874819a4a44e91a505a42255/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L221)) how `ngModel` captures changes and updates value/view.

```js
@Input('ngModel') model: any;
...

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this._checkForErrors();
  if (!this._registered) this._setUpControl();
  if ('isDisabled' in changes) {
    this._updateDisabled(changes);
  }

  if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
    this._updateValue(this.model);
    this.viewModel = this.model;
  }
}
```

and this is the [implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e9faf8c78beba95a874819a4a44e91a505a42255/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L153) of `isPropertyUpdated`

```js
export function isPropertyUpdated(changes: { [key: string]: any }, viewModel: any): boolean {
  if (!changes.hasOwnProperty('model')) return false;
  const change = changes['model'];

  if (change.isFirstChange()) return true;
  return !looseIdentical(viewModel, change.currentValue);
}

// https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/53212db3ed48fe98c0c0416ae0acee1a7858826e/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts#L13
export function looseIdentical(a: any, b: any): boolean {
  return a === b || typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && isNaN(a) && isNaN(b);
}
```

since there is no change in `model` within `changes: SimpleChanges` `isPropertyUpdated` returns false and view is not updated.

so i tried following hacky workaround to re-initialize the input from scratch and it worked :)

i placed a dummy variable on input to show/hide the element;

```html
<input 
  *ngIf="dummy"
  placeholder="Percentage" 
  type="text" 
  [ngModel]="account.percentage | percent: '1.2-2'"
  (ngModelChange)="updateAssignments($event)"
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}"
  class="ta-r"
/>
```

and whenever `ngModelChange` emits input is hidden and shown immediately

```js
dummy = true;

constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

updateAssignments($event) {
  const cleanEvent = Number($event.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
  this.account.percentage = (cleanEvent / 100);
  this.dummy = false;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.dummy = true;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  console.log("account.percentage:", this.account.percentage);
}
```

==>>> [here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-3k8nz4) <<<==

Comment: This looks very promising! Might not be the purest way to make it work, but if it works, it works! :D Will try this afternoon!

Comment: Yup! Worked! I sent the version into QA this PM, will see if anything comes up but initial tests were fine. Smart workaround, gets exactly the behavior I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

It will only update once you blur the input since you set the ngModelOptions to only update on blur :)

Removing it should do the trick.

Comment: without the `updateOn: blur` it attempts to add the percent sign while the user is still typing. but yes i tried that just to see, and the issue remains even with default (updateOn change)

Comment: It's hard to debug like this, can you provide something like a gist of the code? Or a https://stackblitz.com example?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-ru3ks1)

Comment: see above stackblitz link. it works fine until you try to enter the same value twice in a row

Answer (score 0):

Try `[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'change'}"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-starter-rdxhte?file=src/app/hello.component.html

```
<input placeholder="Percentage" type="text" 
       [ngModel]="account.percentage | percent: '1.0-2'"
       (ngModelChange)="updateAssignments($event)" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'change'}" class="ta-r" />
```

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer, the behaviour for on change is really not usable, as soon as the user types a number, the % gets added. so typing 41 for example ends-up being a strange value like 4.00%1, which does not work.

Also, copy-pasting in 64, triggers the reported problem of the pipe not being applied. (maybe a not-dirty detection or something like that?)